# Add new Individuals to an existing ontology from a dataframe using owlready 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, owl, ontology, owlready

I have the following `dataframe`:

```py
import pandas as pd
    
data = [['onto.modify', 'onto.ModificationAction1']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['queries', 'corpus'])

       queries                corpus
0      onto.modify            onto.ModificationAction1
```

The elements of `corpus column` are `Individuals` of a particular `Class` of an `ontology` called  `ontology2`.

I want to add the elements of the `queries column` as `individuals` to the same `Class` that the elements of the `corpus column` belong to.

For example, if the `onto.ModificationAction1` belong to the `ontology2.Thing class` the same must be for the `ontology2.modify`.

Initially, I loop over the `corpus columns` to find in which `Class` each `Individual` belongs to:

```py
for elements in df["corpus"]:
    print (element.is_a)
```

However, I get back:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_a'

So how do I solve this error and eventually perform what I am describing above in the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error happens because values in your dataframe are strings, not individuals. You have to look up an individual based on its name using `search()` or `search_one()` (see [documentation](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/onto.html#simple-queries)). This code should do the job:

```python
import pandas as pd
import owlready2

data = [['onto.modify', 'onto.ModificationAction1']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['queries', 'corpus'])

onto = owlready2.get_ontology("http://test.org/onto.owl")


class Action(owlready2.Thing):
    namespace = onto


modification_action = Action(name="ModificationAction1")

for row in df.iterrows():
    row_series = row[1]
    # Trow away ontology name, get only individual name
    corpus_individual_name = row_series['corpus'].split('.', 1)[1]
    # Find individual
    corpus_individual = onto.search_one(iri=onto.base_iri + corpus_individual_name)
    # Get individual classes
    corpus_classes = corpus_individual.is_a
    # Trow away ontology name, get only individual name
    query_individual_name = row_series['queries'].split('.', 1)[1]
    # Create new individual with first class of old individual
    new_individual = corpus_classes[0](name=query_individual_name)
    # In case old individual is multiclass, add remaining classes to new individual
    for corpus_class in corpus_classes[1:]:
        new_individual.is_a.append(corpus_class)

for i in onto.individuals():
    print(i, i.is_a)
```

You can see the new individual in the output along with its class.

```
onto.ModificationAction1 [onto.Action]
onto.modify [onto.Action]
```

P.S.: I'm assuming here that you have only one ontology -- `onto`. If not, you should either 1) Have a lookup dictionary for ontologies to map `"onto"` into actual ontology object/IRI, or 2) instead of `“onto.”` prefix specify full IRI in your dataframe and lookup ontology by IRI.